# Process finished with exit code 0 in nse

Tags: python

I have just started python, basically I am from finance stream. I wanted to import data from nse(national stock exchange). I have installed nsepy package and tried to run the below code just as a beginner, but when I ran it, it was showing process finished with exit code 0.

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date

from pandas import DataFrame

data: DataFrame = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=date(2020, 1, 1), end=date(2020, 1, 31))
data[['Close']].plot()
```

Comment: Change it to `data = get_history...`  without `: DataFrame`.  It runs in jupyter notebook.

Comment: exit code 0 means that the program finished with no errors... Were you expecting it to do something and it didn't?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the `: DataFrame` as mentioned in the commends.

Also you are ploting the data in the wrong way. Please use following code:

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=date(2020, 1, 1), end=date(2020, 1, 31))
plt.plot(data['Close'])  # adding 'Close' column to the plot
                         # reduced unnecessary square brackets
plt.show()  # display the plot
```

Enjoy!